# Neo4j & Bolt with 3.2

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j (CE) running on a linux server with only one port open (the one I use for the https connection). It's very difficult for me to open any other port.

With Neo4j 3.0, it worked like a charm. I've just installed the 3.2, and I can't manage any more to connect to the Neo4j browser. I get the UI, but when I tried ":serve connect", I now get a "Host" field (together with the Username and Password"). I've tried many combinations, and I always get the message "N/A: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. (...)".

By default, the host field is "bolt://[my-server-name]:7687", which is not reachable from my browser (and I see in my browser webdev console that it tries to reach it, and fails).

I tried in the neo4j.conf to set "dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=false", or to check/uncheck the "Use bolt+routing" box in the "browser settings" of the neo4j browser.

Is there any way to use Neo4j 3.2 with only one port open ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to reach the database itself directly over one (http or https) connection ... however ... if you want to use the Neo4j Browser you currently have no other option than to use the bolt protocol (and that requires an extra port). The browser does currently only connect over bolt. This is an open issue for the Neo4j development team.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found this with more details : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/511